# Parallel jobs using a CMake generated makefile (no speed improvement)

Tags: makefile, cmake, fortran

I have been doing some testing on a project that I recently started building with CMake. Before moving to CMake I noticed significant improvements in build time when using the `-j` option for `make` with my handwritten Makefile.

Now with CMake I do the same thing and there isn't any noticeable increase in speed. Whether I run with `-j` or not, I get four processes for `make.exe`, though only one of them is clocking CPU time and never uses more the 25% of the CPU.

In general, The CMake generated Makefile is much slower than my handwritten Makefile. A quick test shows build times for both CMake and handwritten makefiles with and without the `-j` flag:

```
CMake: "make -j all" = 7min
CMake: "make all" = 7min
Handwritten: "make -j all" = 2min
Handwritten: "make all" = 4min
```

In general, CMake is much slower and doesn't seem to utilize parallel jobs.

Can anyone explain why I'm not seeing any improvements?

(Building a Fortran program with gfortran and using CMake's auto-detect dependency feature...though I don't know if that's relevant to what I'm seeing).

Here's my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
## CMake Version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

## Project Name
project(PROJECT)

## Use FORTRAN
enable_language(Fortran)

## Release compiler options
set (CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3 -cpp -ffree-line-length-none -fimplicit-none")

## Debug compiler options
set (CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -cpp -ffree-line-length-none -fimplicit-none")

## Set directory for FORTRAN modules
set (CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/modules")

## Build Executable
add_executable(EXE 
           Source1.f90 
           Source2.f90         
           .
           .
           . 
           Source219.f90
           Source220.f90)
```

And here's my original Makefile:

```
PROG = PROGRAM.exe

SRCS = Source1.f90 Source2.f90 ... Source219.o Source220.o

OBJS = Source1.o Source2.o ... Source219.o Source220.o

LIBS =  

VPATH = src
BUILDDIR = debug
F90 = gfortran
F90FLAGS = -g -cpp -ffree-line-length-none -fimplicit-none

all: $(PROG)

$(PROG): $(OBJS)
    $(F90) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)


clean:
    erase -f $(BUILDDIR)$(PROG) $(BUILDDIR)\$(OBJS) $(BUILDDIR)\*.mod

.SUFFIXES: $(SUFFIXES) .f90

.f90.o:
     $(F90) $(F90FLAGS) -c $<

Source1.o: Dependency1.o Dependency2.o ... DependencyN.o

Source2.o: Dependency1.o Dependency2.o ... DependencyN.o

.
.
.

Source219.o: Dependency1.o Dependency2.o ... DependencyN.o

Source220.o: Dependency1.o Dependency2.o ... DependencyN.o
```

Comment: Can you show your `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: Just posted my CMakeLists.txt file

Comment: And your original Makefile, too.

Comment: You still need "-j".  Try this:  MAKEFLAGS="-j 4" make

Comment: @Offirmo, just added my Makefile

Comment: @PaulBeckingham I am using `-j` when calling make on the CMake generated Makefile.

Comment: That might be fortran-specific thing. What are these dependencies mentioned in Makefile?

Comment: They are other SourceX.o files. For example, Source1.o uses a function from Source2.o.

Comment: Could you also show the makefile cmake created?

Comment: All 2133 lines? Is there really anything meaningful that you can get from the CMake generated file? I can never make sense of the generated makefiles. Is there something in particular you'd like to see in the makefile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this on windows?  If so it is because the windows version of gmake does not have a job server and recursive makefiles are not parallel.   I am assuming that when you wrote make.exe that means windows.   I think CVS gmake has a jobs server now.   The cygwin gmake also supports the job server.

This link might help you:

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/make-w32/2011-07/msg00002.html

Comment: Then how would parallelisation work with his custom Makefile if it was a missing feature of make ?

Comment: His custom makefile is not recursive.  It does not call make from make.  CMake generated makefiles do.  See here:  http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Why_does_CMake_generate_recursive_Makefiles.3F

Comment: Interesting. That may be the reason, then.

Comment: Thanks, Bill! That's definitely what's going on. Here's some directions for fixing this using until job server is supported in the official release of MinGW: http://mingw-users.1079350.n2.nabble.com/Updated-mingw32-make-3-82-90-cvs-20120823-td7578803.html

Comment: Glad to know there is a fix now without having to use cygwin.